# JQuery "Click" function isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with javascript (jquery) and html integration...

HTML:

```
<div id="arrows">
<div id="slideup"></div>
<div id="slidedown"></div>
</div>
```

as you see i have 2 divs with id slideup and slidedown, after page loads i change first div-s id with newID1, and if user clicks slidedown div, newID1 changes to slideup again, i have two functions and first is starting when element with slideup is clicked, second is starting when element with slidedown is clicked, after newID1 changes to slideup, function which must be started when slideup clicked dont works... see JS code below...

JavaScript (JQuery):

```
$(function(){
    lastbul="bul1";
    i=1;
    $("#slideup").attr("id", "newID1");
    $("#slideup").click(function (){
        i--;
        console.log(i);
    }
    $("#slidedown").click(function (){
        i++;
        console.log(i);
    if (lastbul=="bul1") $("#newID1").attr("id", "slideup");
            else  if (lastbul==sliderPics[sliderPics.length-1].id) $("#newID2").attr("id", "slidedown");
}
```

sliderPics is array, which works fine, don't need to show that...

Comment: bind the events to $('document').on('click', '#slideup', function() {
   // code
});

Comment: no, there isnt any errors, slideup function even isnt loging i variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here :

```
$("#slideup").attr("id", "newID1");
$("#slideup").click(function (){
```

Just after first line, there's no more any `#slideup` element so the second line doesn't do any binding.

Change it to

```
$("#slideup").attr("id", "newID1").click(function (){
```

Answer (score 0):

here the second line needs to be changed. It does not do any binding. Change the second line into

```
  $("#slideup").attr("id", "newID1").click(function ()
 { **the code here**
```